# Create reusable switches with javascript and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, controls, toggle

I'm currently developing a web interface which has some custom controls, one of which is a toggle switch. This is a rough example of what I should look like:

The interface
[image]

I've made this switch in illustrator and exported it as a .svg, which results in a rect (the base) and a circle (the sliding part). When the toggle switch is clicked, i want the base to change colors, a variable to be set or reset, and the slider to move 16px to the right. I know how i could do this by changing the style property of each different element, but i'd like to know how (if) this can be done with one global id for the whole switch. I am using css and javascript and would like to stick to these languages.

In short, this is what i am looking to achieve: I want to use one id for reference in javascript, and would like to toggle a variable (and styles) with the switch. This way, if i use 5 switches, every switch can be toggled independently.

This is what i already have:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="36px" height="18px" class="Switch" id="Switch1" checked="false">
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="SwitchGradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%"> //gradient for slider
        <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#E6EEF2" />
        <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#D7DDE0" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<rect x="3.25" y="3.25" width="27" height="11" class="BaseSlider" rx="6px" ry="6px" id="SwitchBase1"/> //base of the switch
<circle cx="9" cy="9" r="8.5" class="SwitchSlider" id="SwitchSlider1"/> //slider of the switch
```

and this is my javascript function:

```
function SwitchClick() {
Slider_Clicked = !Slider_Clicked; // toggle boolean
if (Slider_Clicked) {
    SwitchBase.style.fill = "#3EBEE5"; //make blue
    SwitchSlider.style = "transform: translateX(16px)"; //move to right
} else {
    SwitchBase.style.fill = "#D7DDE0"; // make grey
    SwitchSlider.style = "transform: translateX(0px)"; //move to left
}
```

Any help on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: hey! how do you attach the js clickHandler to the svg currently?

Comment: Why make it so hard with an SVG and JS. You can simply restyle a checkbox with CSS and achieve the same result without an SVG and JS

Comment: @Luke ik have a loop that runs through all elments with the class "Switch" and attaches event listeners.

Comment: @SuperDJ could you provide a link to more information about this? I'm especially interested in how the animations for the svg-rect and svg-circle would work. Thanks in advance guys, i appreciate it!

Comment: @JohannesWerbrouck You can take a look at an attempt I made: https://superdj.github.io/material/components/selection-controls.html the source for it: https://github.com/SuperDJ/material/blob/master/src/sass/components/_selection.scss